# How to select the filter position instead of the actual name of it?

Tags: vba, for-loop, filter

I'm trying to define the filter of my list in a dynamic way, instead of having to type the actual name of it.

```
Sub Macro2()

ActiveSheet.Range("$C$2:$E$6").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="April"

End Sub
```

In the example above, I don't want to type April. I wish I could type `>Criteria1=1` or `2`, and so on. The final result is the possibility of use the filters within a for loop.

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate? There are many ways to use the `.AutoFilter` feature (the `xlOr` operator, filtering on an array, etc). What are you trying to do?

Comment: If I have 10 options to select and apply on my filter, I'm looking for a way to select the options 1,2 and 6 for instance. I don't want to type the name of each one in the code, just "select" the position/option.

Comment: Have you tried storing your 10 options in an array, an then pulling them by index? e.g. `criterion = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August")` and then `Criteria1:=criterion(3)`, keeping in mind that implicitly-sized arrays are 0-based. Or better, grab the headings from the worksheet into a 1D array (that would be 1-based), and use that instead of hard-coding it.

Comment: Thanks, Mathieu. It works this way...